# Access class variable from another newly created class

Tags: c#

I have code like this:

```
class First
{
    public int a { get; set; }
    public int b { get; set; }
    public int c = 2;
    public _second;

    public First()
    {
        _second = new Second(c);
        this.a = _second.a;
        this.b = _second.b;
    }
}


class Second
{
    public int a;
    public int b;

    public Second(int c)
    {
        if(c == 0)
        {
            a = 1;
            b = 2;
        }
        else
        {
            a = -1;
            b = -2;
        }
    }
}
```

How can I pass `a` and `b` from `First` class into second class and then directly from second class set their values withohut using `static` as declaration in `First` class.

I have tried this:

```
class First
{
    public int a;
    public int b;
    public int c = 2;
    public _second;

    public First()
    {
        _second = new Second(a, b, c);
    }
}


class Second
{
    public Second(int a, int b, int c)
    {
        if(c == 0)
        {
            a = 1;
            b = 2;
        }
        else
        {
            a = -1;
            b = -2;
        }
    }
}
```

but it is not doing the job.

Comment: Pass the instance of First to a constructor in Second

Answer (score 2):

You can simply add a constructor in the Second class that receives the instance of First and updates the public variables of the instance passed

```
public class Second
{
    public Second(int a, int b, int c)
    {
        // old constructor if still needed
        ...
    }
    public Second(First f)
    {
        int sign = f.c == 0 ? 1 : -1;
        f.a = 1 * sign;
        f.b = 2 * sign;
    }
}
```

By the way, I suggest to use properties instead of public fieds.

```
public class First
{
    public int a {get;set;}
    public int b {get;set;}
    public int c {get;set;} = 2;
    public Second _second {get;set;}

    public First()
    {
        _second = new Second(this);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**
Looking at your image it is clear what is the source of your problem. You are receiving a Form class instance in your *Forma* constructor. You need to receive a Main instance like

```
 public Forma(Main form, int modulID) 
 {
     .....
 }
```

The base class **Form** has no knowledge of methods defined in custom form classes. In alternative you can still receive a Form instance but you need to add something like this

```
 public Forma(Form form, int modulID) 
 {
     Main m = form as Main;
     if(m != null) 
        m.helpWindow = new Help(modulID);
 }
     .....
 }
```

Comment: I cannot access it with `f.a` since it is not `static`

Comment: Try it. This doesn't require any static class

Comment: But the two classes are _private_ Are they in the same file? Add the public qualifier before the class name

Comment: It is because I am requesting `based class` in `Second` class and it really doesn't have that property...

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the fields as `ref` meaning that you pass a reference to the field passed as parameter not the value. This means changes to the fields inside the `Second` constructor will be reflected in the `First` class

```
class First
{
    public int a;
    public int b;
    public int c = 2;
    public Second _second;

    public First()
    {
        _second = new Second(ref a, ref b, c);
    }
}


class Second
{
    public Second(ref int a, ref int b, int c)
    {
        if (c == 0)
        {
            a = 1;
            b = 2;
        }
        else
        {
            a = -1;
            b = -2;
        }
    }
}
```

You can pass by `ref` to any method not just a constructor. You should read more about this topic, [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/passing-reference-type-parameters) for example

Comment: One change I haven't written, I declare variables like this: `publilc int a { get; set; }` so  get error when I try using ref `a property or indexer may not be passed as an out or ref parameter`

Comment: @AleksaRistic This only works for fields or local variables, if you want to use properties, you can either declare them with a backing field and use the backing field as a ref parameter, or use the other answer, which is for properties, but takes a dependency from Second to First (not a bad thing necessarily)

Answer (score 0):

I accomplished it with `Interface`.

```
public interface IClass
{
    int a { get; set; }
    int b { get; set; }
}

class First : IClass
{
    public int a { get; set; }
    public int b { get; set; }
    public int c = 2;
    public _second;

    public First()
    {
        _second = new Second(this, c);
    }
}


class Second
{
    public Second(IClass ic, int c)
    {
        if(c == 0)
        {
            ic.a = 1;
            ic.b = 2;
        }
        else
        {
            ic.a = -1;
            ic.b = -2;
        }
    }
}
```